# in this code i am reading all pdfs in a folder and then getting the only 14 line of each pdf. But the output showa the 14 line of only first pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox

In this code i am reading all pdfs in a folder and then getting only 14 lines of each pdf but the output shows the 14 lines of only first pdf .

Please help me resolve above issue each time i am just getting the 14 line of first pdf only.

```
        package pdf;
        
        import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
        import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
        import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
        
        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.io.Writer;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        
        public class pd extends PDFTextStripper {
            
            static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        
            public pd() throws IOException {
            }
        
            public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
            {
                int li;
                //reading all pdfs in a folder
                File directoryPath = new File("C:\\Users\\Sanjeev\\Desktop\\New folder");
                PDDocument document = null;
                 //List of all files and directories
                    File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles();
                    System.out.println("List of files and directories in the specified directory:");
                try
                {
                     
                     
                    //getting each pdf information one by one
                    for(File fi : filesList) {
                        
                    System.out.println("File name: "+fi.getName());
                    System.out.println("File path: "+fi.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("Size :"+fi.getTotalSpace());
                    System.out.println(" ");
                   
                    
                    //reading each pdf line by line
                    document = PDDocument.load(new File(fi.getAbsolutePath()));
                    
                    PDFTextStripper stripper = new pd();
                    stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
                    stripper.setStartPage( 0 );
                    stripper.setEndPage( document.getNumberOfPages() );
          
                    Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                   // System.out.println(document);
                    stripper.writeText(document, dummy);            
                     
                    // printing line number 14 of each pdf
                    li = 0;
                    for(String line:lines){
                        
                        li++;
                        //System.out.println(li+"-------------"+line);
                        if(li==14)
                        {
                            System.out.println(li+"     "+line);
                                                
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    }   
                  }
                
                finally {
                  if( document != null ) {
                        document.close();
                        }
                    }
            }
        
            protected void writeString(String str, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
                lines.add(str);
                
                // you may process the line here itself, as and when it is obtained
            }
        
        
        }`
```

Comment: Whom are you quoting, and why three times?

Answer (score 1):

Since `lines` is `static` you will simply accumulate all lines in that one `List` and the code will always print line 14 of the first document added to it. You might need to clear the `List` too.